# Unable to convert epoch timestamp into "dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss" format in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've read a file in pyspark, downloaded from s3 bucket which is batched by the kinesis firehose delivery stream, to analyse the data in pyspark application and again upload the processed the file in new aws s3 bucket.

I've written code to read the file from local machine which I've downloaded from s3 bucket.
I want to convert the timestamp in the json payload to this format :-

```
dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Here is my code:-

```
        import pyspark
        from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
        from pyspark.sql import functions as f
        from pyspark.sql import types as t
        spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('demo').getOrCreate()
        d = spark.read.json('firehose-ds-iot-data-to-s3-1-2023-01-10-14-31-00-f23001c7-7759-38ca-9f14-4682cc39ae89')
        d.show()
        d.withColumn('ts',f.date_format(d.ts.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType()),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
        d.select('ts').show(truncate=False)
```

Here is my dataset:-

```
    +-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
    |Active-Import|Active-Power|Pyranometer|Temperature|Voltage-1|device_name|           ts|
    +-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.65| inHand-RTU|1673361060486|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.44| inHand-RTU|1673361075375|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.44| inHand-RTU|1673361090384|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.44| inHand-RTU|1673361105397|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.44| inHand-RTU|1673361120532|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.43| inHand-RTU|1673361135503|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.43| inHand-RTU|1673361150520|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   239.27| inHand-RTU|1673361165428|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   236.14| inHand-RTU|1673361180435|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   236.14| inHand-RTU|1673361195440|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   236.03| inHand-RTU|1673361210450|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   236.03| inHand-RTU|1673361225498|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   236.08| inHand-RTU|1673361240595|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   236.08| inHand-RTU|1673361255512|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   236.09| inHand-RTU|1673361270490|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   235.96| inHand-RTU|1673361285544|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   235.96| inHand-RTU|1673361300800|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   235.94| inHand-RTU|1673361315630|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   235.94| inHand-RTU|1673361330528|
    |         2.57|           0|          0|       25.3|   235.75| inHand-RTU|1673361345566|
    +-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+-------------+
    only showing top 20 rows
```

After writing trying the code to convert the epoch timestamp into the "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" format here is my output:-

```
+---------------------+
|ts                   |
+---------------------+
|+54996-09-13 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-13 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-13 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-13 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-13 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-13 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-14 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-14 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-14 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-14 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-14 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-15 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-15 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-15 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-15 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-15 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-15 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-16 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-16 00:00:00|
|+54996-09-16 00:00:00|
+---------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Any help for the issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing the casting with `epoch` instead of `ts`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
d.withColumn('ts', f.date_format(d.epoch.cast(dataType=t.TimestampType()), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

**UPDATE:**

```
d.withColumn("ts",F.to_timestamp(F.col("ts") / 1000, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: It is giving error Dataframe has no attribute "epoch"

Comment: @anonymous_33008899 i've updated the answer,, can you try the second approach?

Comment: Yeah tried the same it still gives an error "An error occurred while calling o82.withColumn.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal RuntimeReplaceable: to_timestamp((cast(ts#186L as double) / cast(1000 as double)), Some(dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss), TimestampType, Some(Asia/Calcutta))
Replacement is unresolved: gettimestamp((cast(ts#186L as double) / cast(1000 as double)), dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss, TimestampType, Some(Asia/Calcutta), false)"

my ts column is of type "bigint"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to convert epoch to date. Be sure that epoch column is StringType, and use your timezone in from_unixtime method.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp, from_unixtime
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

d = ['1673361060486']
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, StringType())
df = df.withColumn('ts',from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(df.value/1000,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),'GMT+1')).show()
```

Comment: Tried the same but its making the entire ts column values null

Comment: Can you share output of df.printSchema(). This should work as long as column is string. Type of epoch column might be Long?

Answer (score 0):

here is a **Spark SQL solution** for this problem.

This will work for all the column datatypes (even long or bigint) as we are
casting the column as string before conversion.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType

temp = [1673361050500,1673361048511,1673361040512]
df = spark.createDataFrame(temp, LongType())
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql("select value, cast(value as string)/1000 as epochseconds, from_unixtime(cast(value as string)/1000 ,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') as timestamp from df").show(5,False)
```

This output for the following code snippet will be as follows:

```
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|value        |epochseconds    |timestamp          |
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
|1673361050500|1.6733610505E9  |10-01-2023 14:30:50|
|1673361048511|1.673361048511E9|10-01-2023 14:30:48|
|1673361040512|1.673361040512E9|10-01-2023 14:30:40|
+-------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

Please upvote if you found this solution helpful.